# Import multi-module Maven project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I have a project that is to be deployed to different platforms, for now it's Desktop and Android. The project currently is managed by Eclipse, ADT, Maven and m2e. I have usual Maven project structure with parent and child modules, as follows:

```
myproject (POM)
  myproject-desktop (JAR)
  myproject-android (APK)
  myproject-common  (JAR)
```

This structure is handled perfectly in Eclipse, I can successfully use ADT in "myproject-android", while dependencies are resolved through m2e. Furthermore, "myproject-common" is automatically detected as dependency for "myproject-android" and all changes to its sources are automatically reflected in "myproject-android".

Now ADT becomes deprecated and I have to migrate to Android Studio. I tried various ways of importing at least "myproject-android" and "myproject-common" modules to AS and failed to do so. I even tried to recreate all the projects manually, but it does not work either. The main problems is that AS can only handle Android project as a top-level project and never allows me to make it a submodule. It also rejects to import pure-Java projects, like "myproject-common", it wants Android and only Android. Basically I'm OK with the new Gradle build system and the new Android project structure, and I can migrate the Android module to it from Maven, but anyway I have no idea, how to integrate it with everything else.

Is there any way of importing such project structure to IDEA/Android Studio, or do I have to manage Android module separately in AS and everything else in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm faced with the same challenge. How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @Matthias I used IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition with Android plugin instead of Android Studio. It seems that AS is not intended for multimodule projects, it handles only small Android-only projects. It's a strange decision at the least, but fortunately we can use CE as an alternative. In the end I personally switched back to Eclipse, because of other IntelliJ shortcomings.